# can we use all the features of android using html5 or any other for developing websites

Tags: android, html, web-services

Hey I am a newbie to android,
My doubt is what are the limits for a website on an android phone, as we develop android apps to access the different services provided by them like camera,gps,sensors can I access them using a website I hope this question made a sense to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://caniuse.com/ to see a list of items supported by the Android browser.

To interact with the hardware of your phone (GPS, camera, accelerometer, etc.) consider using Phonegap: http://phonegap.com/about/feature/